# listview to string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

i have a  xml parser with lazy adapter, i parse all the data to an list view.

now i would like to grabe all the data from the listivew(wiche is 1 textview per row) and put is in and string array
but i have no idea how i have to do that. because if i Google i only get results on how to use and string array to populate the list.

my parser:

```
TextView txt =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv);
HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
song = data.get(position);     
txt.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_TXT));
```

the method i use (so far) for getting my string array:

```
private String[] txt = {

}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I may misunderstand your question but can't you simple make a method in the `ListView`'s adapter to get the data and put it in a string array? I hope you're not searching for the `TextView`'s from the `ListView`' rows with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the string array in getView() method of listView adapter. like this:--

give the size of strArray same as the size of listView.

```
String strArray[] = new String[<size of Your ListView>]; 

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    TextView textView;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        textView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
    strArray[position] = textView.getText().toString();
    return convertView;
}
```

now u want to use this strArray to other class then either you have to make it static or you could pass this to other class via `intent`.like this:--

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

and then in other `activity class` You should get this String array by putting this code:--

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

and if the class to whom you want to pass the String Array( that is strArray) is not `Activity` then You should make your strArray static like this:

```
public static strArray[];
```

now i think your problem will be solved..

Comment: i get an error on the strArray, what am i supposed to fill in there?

Comment: sorry i dont understand u ... please explain

Comment: i need to use the string array whit all the txt in an other class and i don't know how to do that, can you help?

Comment: it will run for sure because i had tried it out... You just give the size of strArray same as listview's size.. ok